# How to define number of ticks in a grouped factor using in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydat <- structure(list(group = structure(1:6, .Label = c(
  "(0,1e+06]",
  "(1e+06,2e+06]", "(2e+06,3e+06]", "(3e+06,4e+06]", "(4e+06,5e+06]",
  "(5e+06,6e+06]"
), class = "factor"), n = c(
  1446801L, 47133L,
  22577L, 14941L, 10747L, 8703L
), log_n = c(
  6.16040880026537, 4.67332508334081,
  4.3536662329829, 4.17437966574899, 4.031287248877, 3.93966898352233
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

mydat
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   group               n log_n
#>   <fct>           <int> <dbl>
#> 1 (0,1e+06]     1446801  6.16
#> 2 (1e+06,2e+06]   47133  4.67
#> 3 (2e+06,3e+06]   22577  4.35
#> 4 (3e+06,4e+06]   14941  4.17
#> 5 (4e+06,5e+06]   10747  4.03
#> 6 (5e+06,6e+06]    8703  3.94
```

In reality, the number of rows is up to 1000 rows.

Then I tried to make a plot the following way:

```
   p <-  mydat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = group, y = log_n)) +
      geom_col() +
      coord_flip() +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(mydat$group))) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(size = 12))
 p
```

Which produces this:

[image]

What I want to do is to reduce the number of ticks in y-axis (`group`) to just 3 ticks. I tried this but failed:

```
  p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty(mydat$group, n = 3))
```

What's the right way to do it?

---

## Updated

After I tried @astrofunkswag approach. I get this plot where the order is the reversed. What I want is to maintain the same order as before:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
p + scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(mydat$group)), breaks = mydat$group[pretty(1:nrow(mydat), 3)])
```

A couple issues:

- `coord_flip` just puts the `x` value on the vertical axis, but it's still `x`
- Your `group` variable is a factor, not numeric, so you need to either use `scale_x_discrete` as I did in the code above or transform that column some other way

I selected 3 elements from `group` using `pretty` similar to how you did, but you could get different elements if you don't like the resulting plot

Comment: Thanks but the plot is reverse. I want to maintain the order as in my original post. See my updated image.